# Trigger local "OK Google" actions programmatically

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm writing an app that responds to custom voice commands. I want to add the ability to hand some of them off to "OK Google" functionality that handles actions locally (e.g. "launch " or "volume up"). I don't want to hand it off to to the Google Assistant cloud-based APIs, just the local version that handles simple commands that control the device. My app uses the ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH intent to get the spoken text. The goal is that if it's not a command my app handles, it will trigger whatever handles "OK Google" commands with the text it already has.