# How can I launch a react native app using "Ok Google" and open a specific page in the app?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to set a custom phrase in "Ok Google" which opens my app with navigating the user to a specific screen in the app.

I tried the 'google actions' but -as far as I know- it just supports some built-in intents and none of them can do what i want.

Thank you.

Comment: I hope this page will help you https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply, this actions uses built-in intents, should i built a new intent?

Comment: As far as I read, no such thing is possible.There is a question about this content that has not been answered for 3 years. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45965226/trigger-local-ok-google-actions-programmatically İf  you can find  answer this question, please write answer your question.